# Cannot connect to Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core remotely from Windows 7 using RSAT

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access

I've installed [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) to administer my Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core machine.

I get the following error message when trying to connect to the **Server Manager**:

> Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message: Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Make sure that the **`WinRM` service is running** on both machines
   (Windows Server and Windows 7)
2. **Added the server to trusted hosts** on the Windows 7 machine using:
   `winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="WINSRV2"}`
3. **Added the following registry entry** on the Windows 7 machine using:
   `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`
4. **Enabled Remote Management** inbound rule on the server's firewall using `CoreConfigurator 2.0`
5. Made sure that **both machines are in the same subnet** and when I search for network machines on Windows 7, I see the server.
6. Tried running **Server Manager** on the Windows 7 machine normally as well as elevated but with no obvious difference. This resulted in the same error.

Before I did items (2) and (3) above, I was getting a completely different error, which was even more ambiguous. I have now got to this point where the two machines are obviously trying to communicate.

**Question:**

What else should I do to make it work? I would like to run several different remote management tools against my server machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolved

I had to run remote management tools under domain admin account. They connected just fine to my domain controller on Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core. This was stupid, yet I learned something... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Configure the windows firewalls on both sides ;)

Comment: As stated in my question I've configured firewall on the server side. I guess that's all that should be configured there. What about the client side (Windows 7 machine)? What should be configured there?